# SVN with Eclipse Integration

Tags: eclipse, svn

In SVN it is asking a URL what is the meaning of that URL when itergrating that with the Eclipse.

For me am having two Computers , I need to have same Project in both Computers to work from Home and Office with updated one.

So I installed SVN both Places.But while try to to do this

MyProject --> Team --> Share Project-->Location (URL text box appears).

There what I have to give.

Please give me guidance to configure this.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN requires a repository (like all source management applications), which is usually on a web server.

In your case I suggest to not use a SCM, but some synchronisation tool like Dropbox, since only you use the code and no two computers access the code at the same time. This has the advantage that your code will always be up-to-date on both computers automatically.

Alternatively you can create a free repository e.g. on [sourceforge](http://sf.net) or [github](http://github.com) (uses GIT instead of SVN) and manually push changes.